# Running Python script as input in QGIS 3.x Graphical Modeler

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-modeler

I am building a model via QGIS 3.12 Graphical Modeler. There, I want to input Python code just like expressions, vector field,vector layer and use it as a parameter (or may be algorithm if it is possible to build). Any suggestions?